# difference between sacred and sacred one

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the difference between sacred and sacred one?

Sentence - The garden was a sacred one.

Source - https://youtu.be/C5a3pDMGp34?t=151

> Is there any difference between following two sentences?

The Garden was sacred

The garden was a sacred one.

Comment: It's just saying that the adjective "sacred" applies to that garden. As in "The car was a red one." You could equally well say "The garden was sacred", "It was a sacred garden", and so on.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no real difference in what is being communicated. "Sacred one" may be considered a tad more poetic.
2. When it comes to grammar, the structures a slightly different. In both cases "sacred" is an adjective modifying noun "garden". In "the garden was sacred", the construct "noun + (to be) + adjective" is used to link the adjective to the noun. In "the garden was sacred one", we have the pronoun "one" which refers to "garden" and the adjective "sacred" modifies the pronoun.
3. The pronoun "one" can sometimes be used to emphasize the particularity of something, but it's not really the case in the sentence.

Hope this helps.